# snmp.conf how to allow any remote client

Tags: snmp, snmpd, net-snmp

Using linux (Ubuntu) with net-snmp.

I want to allow any remote client to execute snmpget.
The remote client not have to be from the same subnet , so i cannot do this by define subnet.

Now i add line in snmpd.conf for each ip.
like this:

```
rwcommunity community 10.0.0.1
rwcommunity community 10.0.0.2
```

is there a way to do this for all ips?
In addtional try to use this :

```
#  Listen for connections on all interfaces (both IPv4 *and* IPv6)
#agentAddress udp:161,udp6:[::1]:161
```

didn't worked , so  i need to wrote the listening ip.

thank you!!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
rocommunity public
```

But please rethink this. Letting anybody in the world get your SNMP data is generally a bad idea.

Comment: It local netwrok.can you please help on how to listen for connections on all interfaces it dosnt work for me. (without #)